# Make a list of items with progressively increasing CSS propperty

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an HTML `table` rendered such that all the `rows` are `position` `absolute` with progressively increasing `top` property.

```css
.table{
  position: relative;
}
tr{
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
td, th{
  width: 80px;
}
tr:nth-child(1){
  top: 0;
}
tr:nth-child(2){
  top: 25px;
}
tr:nth-child(3){
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th>header 1</th>
  <th>header 2</th>
  <th>header 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>c1</td>
  <td>c2</td>
  <td>c3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>c11</td>
  <td>c22</td>
  <td>c33</td>
</tr>
```

I want to do something like `tr:nth-child(n){top: n*25px;}` instead of repeating it for each row. Is there a way to do this using *pure* CSS?

I know this is not the right way to render a table, I'm still curious if there's a way to make it happen.

Comment: you can do it only with sass file

Comment: why use `position: absolute;` without it table works fine

Comment: I know. But I'm working on something where I need to add position absolute. This is just a simplified question.

Comment: How would you approach it using SASS?

Comment: see my answer please

Answer (score 1):

With only pure css you can not do it...

You can do it with sass file:

See here:https://jsfiddle.net/vpj3ek24/1/

```
 .table{
  position: relative;
}
tr{
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
td, th{
  width: 80px;
}
 @mixin child($n) {
     &:nth-child(#{$n}){
         top:$n*25px;
     }
 }

 div{
     @include child(n);
    }
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Answer (score 0):

Can use `position: static;` and remove `tr:nth-child(1)`.

```
.table{
     position: relative;
   }
   tr{
     position: static;
     height: 25px;
     text-align: center;
   }
   td, th{
     width: 80px;
   }
   /* tr:nth-child(1){
     top: 0;
   }

   tr:nth-child(2){
     top: 25px;
   }
   tr:nth-child(3){
     top: 50px;
   } */
```